# WD external drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive

I have been using a WD external drive for a couple of years with no problems but now I can not read it. The light is on when connected to the laptop, it does the useual  flashing light and you can feel feel the disc rotating but that is it.

In windows explorer it shows the drive (F:) but will not show what is on the drive. Clicking on the drive brings up a warning message - Windows explorer not responding.  This happens to all programs used to try and access the data on the drive, office programs etc. Including EaseUS and Data lifeguard for windows. WD drive utilities program does not even recognize it is connected. Using the Data lifeguard software, this carries out an analysis of drive and then disappears as it shut down. Checking with task manager it does not show it as running but remove the WD drive from the USB port the lifeguard program appears showing the details if the laptop internal drive.

Any one with any idea with what may have cased the issue and what can be done to rectify?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the drive has failed. I would run disk check with cmd on the drive. If it is corrupted, then that can by fixed with a command, but I don't think it is that, I think it is bad sector but run disk check with cmd by running cmd as a administrator. If it is a bad sector, then replace hdd is all you can do.